# Does Visual C++ know what version a project was created with?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++

In a VS 2015 solution, with 100 C++ projects, some projects have different values for the same property.  These projects go back a long time (product is 20+ yrs old).  One such property is the *Linker/Debugging/Generate Debug Info*.  Most projects have the */DEBUG* settings.  A few have */DEBUG:FASTLINK*.

I am looking at the same configuration on both projects.  Drilling into the property sheets does not show where this property is introduced.  If I create a new project it shows the /DEBUG:FASTLINK setting for debug builds.  This leads me the think that there is something in the project file that makes it different; the ones with /DEBUG:FASTLINK are newer then the ones with /DEBUG.  This jives with a MSDN page I found indicating that FASTLINK is now the preferred option.

As an experiment I created a new project that parallels and "old" project.  Both .vcxproj files are in the same directory, just named differently.  The "new" project shows the /DEBUG:FASTLINK property.  In both cases the project file does not set this value it relies on "".  In other words it is not in bold in the property pages dialog.  I was not able to see a useful difference between the two projects.  Both use V140 for the toolset.

My goal is to make the setting the same across all of the projects, without setting it in each project.  One way to do this is to create my own property sheet with these values the way I want.  I would rather bring my projects up to current standards w/o manually recreating 100 projects.

Comment: You may want to edit the project files directly. The files are xml. Use a search and replace. Perhaps in Notepad++

Comment: When you pass `/DEBUG`, the compiler shipped with VS 2017 interprets this as `/DEBUG:FASTLINK`. So you don't actually *need* to change anything.

Comment: This came up because I was trying to get away from that.  In re-setting the project level property to <inherit> I noticed that some projects were different.  I noticed at least one other property as well.  I was trying to pull settings were unneeded _out_ of my projects.

Comment: The FASTLINK option was added in VS2015.  So you surely added those projects recently.  It is not critical, just makes PDB file generation faster.  Change multiple project settings with a single edit by first selecting the projects.

Comment: What I am more interested in is WHY they are different, not how to force them the same (that was the first thing I did).  We have a need to generate the full PDB file(s) as we save them off with the builds to be able to analyse crash dumps.  The new default will not do that for me.  Is there a difference between using the old /DEBUG option, or the apparently new /DEBUG:FASTLINK with the GenreateFull Program Database File set to Yes?  Thanks for the info on FastLink and 2015, that is what I thought.